# Hardlinks and DLLs

Tags: c++, dll, hardlink

I have a shared DLL that I would like to expose as multiple different DLLs with different names in different directories. I figured using hardlinks would work and that running each one would be a different memory space, but from testing it out, it seems to load the shared DLL rather than each hard linked DLL. Furthermore, loading multiple hard linked DLL will just go back to the one that was already loaded/

Does anyone have any suggestions to go around this memory sharing of the hard linked DLLs so that each one will have their own memory?

Note that I don't want to make multiple copies of the DLL because of space constraints.

Comment: Why not copy it? That will be more reliable, by far.

Comment: @MSalters Space restriction, we want to keep the overall size of everything as small as possible